# Responsive menu, <a> height 100%

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

I'm working on a responsive navigation. Its width is 100% of the browser window. its height is calculated so that the 6 anchors in it are squares. I managed to set the div's height with the "dummy-div" and padding-top trick. my next problem is setting the anchors height that the container is filled. I really want the menu to be fixed.
As I want the links to be squares I can't work with absolute values.

the **HTML** looks somehow like that:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        .....
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant snippet of my **CSS**:

```
    .menu {
         top:0;
         bottom:0;
         width: 100%;
         position: fixed;
      }

    .menu .dummy {
         float: left;
         padding-top: 20%;
      }

    .menu a {
         display: inline-block;
         position: relative;
         width: 20%;
         height: 100%;
      }
```

The width of my boxes work perfectly fine, but I'm struggling with the height. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do with `<div class="dummy"></div>`  so I've removed it. if you want the 6 menu items as squares use padding to create the shape:

```
.menu a {
    width: 15.666666667%;       /* (100/6)-1% */
    margin:0 .5%;               /* that 1% applied as margins left & right */
    padding:8.333333334% 0;     /* (100/6)/2 applied as padding top & bottom */
    line-height:0;              /* make sure text has no height */

    float:left;
    background:#303030;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/wazGx/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div inside anchor tag.

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="dummy"></div>
  <a href="#"><div>Link 1</div></a>
        .....
  <a href="#"><div>Link 6</div></a>
</div>
```

Now you can specify height of div via css

```
.menu a div{
height:50px; width:100px;
}
```